# Measuring AUPRC in CatBoost

Tags: machine-learning, precision-recall, catboost

I want to measure area under the curve of precision-recall curve (AUPRC) in catboost, but the `CatBoostClassifier`, doesn not have `AUPRC` as an evaluation metric.Any suggestion that helps me to measure this performance metric will be appreciated.

This is the code I use:

```
model = CatBoostClassifier(
custom_loss=['Accuracy','Precision','Recall','F1','AUC'],
random_seed=42,
logging_level='Silent')
model.fit(
X_train, Y_train,
eval_set=(X_test, Y_test), plot=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Catboost has MAP metric which stands for Mean Average Precision. Pretty much the same as the AUCPR. This is a good [reference article](https://sanchom.wordpress.com/tag/average-precision/) explaining why.

Comment: Could you summarize what the article says in a sentence or two?

Comment: Use references as additional resource and not the main source. If the link is no longer available on the future your answer becomes useless.

Answer (score 0):

To use average precision as metric you can use `eval_metric="PRAUC:use_weights=false` which has the same meaning with `scikit-learn` `average_precision`. This metric is implemented since `catboost` `0.32.1` version.