# How do I utilize the MAP eval metric in Catboost to calculate Mean Average Precision?

Tags: python, catboost

I have been using a custom metric for Precision-Recall AUC in Catboost. However, it iterates slow and is incompatible with GPU. I see [Catboost has a metric "MAP" for Mean Average Precision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54964477/measuring-auprc-in-catboost/64391086#64391086) which is what I need for my (binary) classification model.

When I fit my Catboost Model using MAP as the eval metric I get the error:

> CatBoostError: c:/program files (x86)/go
> agent/pipelines/buildmaster/catboost.git/catboost/private/libs/target/data_providers.cpp:269:
> Groupwise loss/metrics require nontrivial groups

After googling this error (specifically the "Groupwise loss/metrics require nontrivial groups" portion) I have had no luck resolving the issue.

Looking through the [Catboost documentation](https://catboost.ai/docs/concepts/loss-functions-ranking.html) it seems there may be some additional arguments I need to use in order for MAP to work properly as an eval metric. But I do not understand how to implement them.

How do I use MAP as my eval metric in Catboost for a binary classification problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no metric MAP on Catboost. But to use average precision as metric you can use `eval_metric="PRAUC:use_weights=false` which has the same meaning with `scikit-learn` `average_precision` and `MAP` on `XGboost`. This metric is implemented since `catboost` `0.32.1` version.